# Mysql server saves LocalDateTime with 3 hours beyond OS time

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

During the process of the service writing the LocaDateTime to the database, in my case, in a spring boot API with java 8, when saving the attribute configured as TIMESTAMP on the database side and LocaDateTime in the API, that date is being saved with 3 hours beyond the current operating system date.

Suppose I try to do this exactly at 10 in the morning, the date saved to the database should be 11 hours, but in my case it is not working that way ...

```
private LocalDateTime dataLimite;

@PrePersist
public void prepareToSave() {
    String str = "1986-04-08 10:00";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
    this.dataLimite = dateTime.plusHours(1);
}
```

[image: Date into the database]
Apparently it may be noted that it is a problem on the side of the Mysql configuration, but when I test ...

```
SELECT NOW();
```

The result is exactly the date and time of the operating system, so what is the real problem that is occurring? How to fix this issue?

Comment: is all the software/servers in the same timezone?

Comment: Yes, I debugged the application, before saving the date everything is exactly as it should.

Comment: The `>` in Markdown tagging is for quotations, not your own prose. I fixed your formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `LocalDateTime`

Read the documentation more closely.

> This class does not store or represent a time-zone. Instead, it is a description of the date, as used for birthdays, combined with the local time as seen on a wall clock. It cannot represent an instant on the time-line without additional information such as an offset or time-zone.

The `LocalDateTime` class in Java cannot be used to represent a moment. It represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the globe.

This class contains a date and a time-of-day, but purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So if you store, for example, noon on the 23rd of January this year,  we do not know if you meant noon in Tokyo, Kolkata, Paris, or Montréal… all different moments, hours apart, happening earlier in the east and later in the west.

So you are using the wrong class. For a moment, use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`.

## `TIMESTAMP`

Read the documentation more carefully.

The `TIMESTAMP` type in MySQL 8 is akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.  This type represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

The documentation [explains](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) that a moment submitted to the database is adjusted to UTC for storage.

> MySQL converts `TIMESTAMP` values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.

This explains your problem. You were implicitly relying on the current default time zone to be assigned to an object of the wrong type in Java that lacked any time zone. **Never write code that relies on the current default time zone** (or locale) of your server, as that lies outside your control as a programmer. Instead, always specify explicitly your desired/expected time zone. Or better, just work in UTC whenever possible.

For best results stick to UTC when exchanging values with the database.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;

myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

To view that moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Australia/Sydney" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both modern and legacy) and in standard SQL.]